# Reboot my rooter with python giving error with pxssh

Tags: python, pexpect, pxssh

i want to reboot my rooter using this code:

```
from pexpect.pxssh import pxssh


s = pxssh.pxssh()
s.login('Adress','username','password')
s.sendline('reboot')
s.prompt()
s.logout
```

But it's giving me this error:

```
from pexpect import ExceptionPexpect, TIMEOUT, EOF, spawn
ImportError: cannot import name 'spawn' from 'pexpect' (C:\Users\Hama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pexpect\__init__.py)
```

All what i need is to reboot my rooter one time, that's all, are there other solution to do that under windows 10?

Any help is appreciated, thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a router waiting for the end of a command. Try to use `EOF` or `\n`

Comment: How to use that? sorry i am newbie